# Can QGIS clip a raster after Hillshade has been run on it?

Tags: qgis, raster, hillshade

I've been trying to clip a raster layer with a shapefile. I already ran Hillshade on the raster, but the clip operation produces a clipped raster file, but the hillshade has been removed. Is this how it works?

Comment: What do you mean by "the hillshade has been removed"?

Comment: The raster was returned to its original DEM. The hillshade effect was gone.

Comment: Try "Right click on the hillshade > Styles > Copy Style" before clipping, then "Right click on the clipped image > Styles > Paste Style" after clipping.